# Highcharts : How do i align data labels above the axis in column chart?

Tags: highcharts

I am plotting the values dynamically in highcharts column charts. I have displayed the data labels with -90 degree rotation to avoid the overlapping. But It has some issues like the values are cut off by the axis.
I have tried the y offset option. But The values are plotted dynamically. So I couldn't set this value as fixed one.

JS Fiddle : [a link](https://jsfiddle.net/keerthi158/t15eg1qm/)

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
    type: 'column'
},
title: {
    text: 'World\'s largest cities per 2014'
},
subtitle: {
    text: 'Source: <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_proper_by_population">Wikipedia</a>'
},
xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    labels: {
        rotation: -45,
        style: {
            fontSize: '13px',
            fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
        }
    }
},
yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
        text: 'Population (millions)'
    }
},
legend: {
    enabled: false
},
tooltip: {
    pointFormat: 'Population in 2008: <b>{point.y:.1f} millions</b>'
},
series: [{
    name: 'Population',
    data: [
        ['Shanghai', 2341.7],
        ['Lagos', 165.1],
        ['Istanbul', 14.2],
        ['Karachi', 14.0],
        ['Mumbai', 12.5],
        ['Moscow', 12.1],
        ['São Paulo', 11.8],
        ['Beijing', 11.7],
        ['Guangzhou', 11.1],
        ['Delhi', 11.1],
        ['Shenzhen', 10.5],
        ['Seoul', 10.4],
        ['Jakarta', 10.0],
        ['Kinshasa', 9.3],
        ['Tianjin', 9.3],
        ['Tokyo', 9.0],
        ['Cairo', 8.9],
        ['Dhaka', 8.9],
        ['Mexico City', 8.9],
        ['Lima', 8.9]
    ],
    dataLabels: {
        useHTML:true,
            crop:false,
        enabled: true,
        rotation: -90,
        color: '#000000',          
        inside:true,
        style: {
            fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif',
            fontWeight: "bold"
                , fontSize: "15px"
        }
    }
}]
```

});

 
`

```
<div id="container" style="min-width: 300px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">
</div>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set yAxis type to logarithmic, and its minorTickInterval to 0.1. Logarithmic scale fits to this type of data perfectly. Lets look at code below:

```
yAxis: {
    type: 'logarithmic',
    minorTickInterval: 0.1,
    title: {
        text: 'Population (millions)'
    }
},
```

Here is your refactored JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/daniel_s/x5oxyt2v/

Best Regards!

Comment: Thanks @daniel_s. Works Well.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the [align](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.columnrange.dataLabels.align) attribute to "left" could work.

```
dataLabels: {
    align: "left"
}
```

See here: https://jsfiddle.net/t15eg1qm/3/

Comment: I am displaying the data dynamically. So It is not a fixed one. If i use the align property to left, sometimes the values go out of the graph ie on top half of the labels are inside and half of the labels are outside. A logarithmic yAxis gives the center alignment and display datalabels nicely.